# convert jcas object to json object

Tags: java, json, uima, uimafit

I require the output in json format, for which I have to convert the jcas object in json.
I tried using the method given in uima guide but was not successful.

Can anyone suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using [JsonCasSerializer](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.7.0/references.html#ugr.ref.json.usage) you can do this

```
final String note = "Serum Cholesterol 154 150 250 mgs/dl\n-\nSerum Triglycerides 67 90 200 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum HDL: Cholesterol 38 35 55 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum LDL: Cholesterol 49 85 150 mgs/d1\n-\nSerum VLDL: Cholesterol 13 10 40 mgs/dl\n-\nTotal Cholesterol / HDL Ratio: 3.90\";
final JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
jcas.setDocumentText(note);

final AnalysisEngineDescription aed = getFastPipeline(); 
SimplePipeline.runPipeline(jcas, aed);
CAS cas = jcas.getCas();

JsonCasSerializer jcs = new JsonCasSerializer();
jcs.setPrettyPrint(true); // do some configuration

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jcs.serialize(cas, sw); // serialize into sw

System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

This gave me an output of the document in JSON format.